# Concavity of function $\sin(x^2)$.

Tags: derivatives

I want to check where the function is convex and where concave.
For this I need to calculate the second derivative test:

I got $f''(x) = 2*\cos(x^2) -4*x^2(\sin(x^2))$ and this derivative should be equal to 0 in order to reach my goal.

so: $f''(x) = \cos(x^2) - 2*x^2(\sin(x^2)) = 0$

I have simplified this to $\sin^2(x)*(2x^2 - 1) = 1$

But what should I do next?  Because all my previous examples i could simplify to something like: $x*(x+1) = 0$

Comment: $\cos(x^2)\neq \cos^2(x)$, so your reformulation is incorrect. That said, I am not sure how to handle this yet

Comment: This problem does not have a nice solution: convex for |x|<0.8083, concave for 0.8083<|x|<1.8145, convex for 1.8145<|x|<2.5222, ... If the previous ones were easy, are you sure you have stated it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The sine function is convex where negative and concave where positive, since it is a solution of the differential equation $f''=-f$. *Almost* the same holds for $\sin(x^2)$. We have:
$$ \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\,\sin(x)^2 = 2\cos(x^2)-4x^2\sin(x^2) $$
hence the changes of concavity happen at the solutions of:
$$ \tan(x^2) = \frac{1}{2x^2} $$
that cannot be written in a explicit way. However, the solutions of $\tan(t)=\frac{1}{2t}$ get closer and closer to $\pi\mathbb{Z}$ as $|t|\to +\infty$. So we may say that $\sin(x^2)$ is convex where negative and concave where positive, *provided that $x$ is sufficiently far from the origin and $\sin(x^2)$ is sufficiently positive/negative*.